# Connect Hyper-v Manager on domain PC to a workgroup Hyper-V Server

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

We have a small lab network:

- There is 1 server running Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V Core. It is not joined to a domain.
- My PC is part of a domain, running Windows 10

When I was running Windows 8.1, I was able to setup a user on the Hyper-V server with the same username and password as my domain user, run winrm quickconfig, disabled the Firewall (acceptable for the lab) and I could run the Hyper-V manager from my desktop.

On Windows 10, I have followed the same steps but I am not able to connect. Instead I get an error:

> An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "ServerName". Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server.
>
> The operation on computer 'ServerName' failed: WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer ServerName. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly.

I have confirmed that I am able to connect to the Hyper-V management tools from a different Windows 8.1 installation, the service is definitely running and is available for remote access.

How can I manage a workgroup Hyper-V server from a Domain connected Windows 10 Desktop?

Comment: The error looks like you have a name resolution problem. How are you resolving the name of the Hyper-V host? Can you resolve the name of the Hyper-V host from the Windows 10 computer?

Comment: I can ping and RDP to the server using the server name and IP address. I have tried connecting Hyper-v manager using server name and IP address

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue, was working fine on Windows 8.1 won't find the computer on Windows 10! I have set the hosts file with the servers IP, and I can ping and RDP like @Greg reports!

Comment: I have the same problem. I managed to get PowerShell remoting to work using basic authentication. Maybe Hyper-V manager is only using Kerberos? Maybe there is a way to tell it to use basic auth?

Comment: Trying this out, https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/3fi7nr/problem_accessing_hyperv_2012_r2_from_windows_10/

Comment: @PedroCosta - Just tried that - same problem

Comment: yah didn't work for me either... :(

Comment: Have you tried running the hyper-v manager console with the runas utility?